# I'm having trouble trying to intepret what is being stated in the following C# documentations concerning Namespaces?

Tags: meaning-in-context, programming

According to this statement in the C# MS doc [Accessibility Levels (C# Reference)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/accessibility-levels)

> Access modifiers are not allowed on namespaces. Namespaces have no access restrictions.

However, the following statement in the C# MS doc [namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/namespace) contradicts the above.

> Namespaces implicitly have public access.

Does this mean that a namespace declaration implicitly consists of the public access modifier as part of its definition? (similar to how a constant member declaration implcitly consists of the static keyword as part of its definition).

Comment: This looks more like a programming question than one about the English language.

Comment: C# isn't English.

Comment: @HotLicks But the documentation is. Sorta.

Comment: @Lawrence Rarely

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more likely to receive a good answer on https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

"Namespaces have no access restrictions." is a bit misleading.

It means that Namespaces have a public access level, but modifiers can't be applied to it, so that will always be the case.